# ArrayList keeps filling with same data

Tags: android, json, arraylist, android-alertdialog

I have a very wierd problem. I have some data which I show in a Dialog. If I close the App and reopen it again my ArrayList always adds the original data again (First 5 entries -> close & reopen -> 10 entries -> close & reopen -> 15 entries etc.).

This is how I parse my data into the ArrayList (This only happens once in my TabHost):

```
JSONArray jPDFs = json.getJSONArray("pdfs");
            for (int i = 0; i < jPDFs.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c3 = jPDFs.getJSONObject(i);

                String pdf_title = c3.getString("title");
                String pdf_url = c3.getString("url");

                pdfListTitle.add(pdf_title);
                pdfListTitle2.add(pdf_title);
                pdfListURL.add(pdf_url);
            }
```

And here is my Code where I show the dialog with the parsed data:

```
public void showDialog() {
    items = null; // have tried with and without...
    builder = null; // have tried with and without...

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    Log.e(TabHost.LOG_TAG, "pdfListTitle=" + TabHost.pdfListTitle.size()); // this always hops from 5 -> 10 -> 15 on every reopen (without killing the app with a taskkiller...)

    items = TabHost.pdfListTitle.toArray(new CharSequence[TabHost.pdfListTitle.size()]);

    builder.setTitle(R.string.choose_document);
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewpdf);
            wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            wv.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
                    + TabHost.pdfListURL.get(item));
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Thanks alot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have taken **pdfListTitle** as **static** in **TabHost**, this may be problem

**pdfListTitle**  should initialize every time when your activity call

for example you can write this code in `onCreate()` method like this

```
ArrayList<T> pdfListTitle;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  pdfListTitle = new ArrayList<T>; <----

}
```

Comment: Looks like this is it! But how can I change it? Because now it says: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field TabHost.pdfListTitle

Comment: So I have to do this in my Tab? Or in my TabHost?
Because now I instantiate and fill my ArrayList in the TabHost and get the entries in the Tab itself...

Comment: I was able to fix it with this solution! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in the method  `TabHost.pdfListTitle.toArray(..)`, you should reset the list that you fill with data every time..

Comment: Clear the list everytime before you populate data into it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and naive workaround is to add

`pdfListTitle.clear()`

before you're filling list with data.

But this won't resolve the problem that the method is invoked each time the dialog is shown, unless you need it.

Answer (score 0):

As previous users said, you should clean your list manually (`pdfListTitle.clear()`), but it is useful to understand the problem deeper.

As I can see, you store your `pdfListTitle` as static field in your class TabHost (by the way, it not very well to use such names like TabHost because there is TabHost in android API (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html). Static fields are initialized at first when classes are loaded. And there is no any warranty when exactly these classes will be unloaded by Android system, cause there is no "closing" application in android. It'll be useful for you to read about class loaders in Java (you can google it very simple).